# Heroku ограничения по работе скриптов

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, heroku

Я загрузил вчера телеграм бота на хостинг Хероку, я хотел бы знать какие есть ограничения по работе моего бота на этом хостинге, а то есть сколько времени он может там работать без отключений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инстанс заснет через полчаса бездействия. Когда сам использовал его, раньше был лимит на 550 часов работы в месяц. Сейчас на сайте не нашел упоминания про это.

Comment: Да всё также - [550 часов в месяц (или 1000, если просто привязать карту)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#:~:text=Personal%20accounts%20are%20given%20a,the%20monthly%20free%20dyno%20quota.).